# Detox build is failing by throwing YogaKit.modulemap' fatal error not found

Tags: react-native, detox

**Detox build is failing by throwing YogaKit.modulemap' fatal error not found**

*Xcode Version:- 11.3
"react": "16.11.0",
"react-native": "0.62.2"
"detox": "13.3.0", tried latest 16 version as well*

But build got succeeded with the below configuration

"dependencies": {
"react": "^16.3.0-alpha.1",
"react-native": "0.59.9"
},
"devDependencies": {
"babel-jest": "22.4.1",
"babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
"detox": "13.3.0",
"jest": "22.4.2",
"mocha": "^5.0.4",
"react-test-renderer": "^16.3.0-alpha.1"

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

**I think latest version of react-native is not compatible with the detox. I tried to get resolve for Yogakit, but ended with no luck.**

Please let me know if anything is required. I would be thankful if someone shared the working config with the latest react-native.

`fatal error: module map file ....../ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap'
      not found
1 error generated.
20 errors generated.
fatal error: module map file '...../ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap'
      not found
1 error generated.
22 errors generated.

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /....../ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/King.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/King.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o /....../ios/King/AppDelegate.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
detox[29631] ERROR: [cli.js] Error: Command failed: xcodebuild -project ios/King.xcodeproj -scheme King -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build`

Comment: This has nothing to do with Detox. Your build is failing. Detox has been tested with 0.62.2 in CI.

Answer (score 31):

take a look at this config in package.json

```
"detox": {
  "configurations": {
    "ios.sim.debug": {
      "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/example.app",
      "build": "xcodebuild -project ios/example.xcodeproj -scheme example -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
      "type": "ios.simulator",
      "device": {
        "type": "iPhone 11 Pro"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and take a look at that

> For React Native 0.60 or above, or any other iOS apps in a workspace (eg: CocoaPods) use -workspace ios/example.xcworkspace instead of -project.

Comment: THANKS! I was driving crazy till you make notice to use workspace instead of proj!

Comment: I am a beginner at this. Can you tell me which files need to be updated to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

This is how I got it working:

1. Open xcworkspace file
2. Click on this :
   http://files.simformsolutions.com.s3.amazonaws.com/simformscreen/ReactN.xcworkspace_2020-09-17_12-48-42.png
3. You will see such available options for your project/app as update
   project settings to recommended :
   http://files.simformsolutions.com.s3.amazonaws.com/simformscreen/ReactN.xcworkspace_2020-09-17_12-49-43.png
4. Click on the warnings and update the project to recommended settings, for all warnings.
5. On Convert to swift 5 available, if you click it, it will specifically show you the YogaKit module, click convert.
6. It will take time and voila!!
7. The build should succeed this time.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode Menu -> File -> Save as Workspace -> (untitled name)
and then open that workspace file in the Xcode,
it will work

- go to ios folder
- open terminal
- pod update

and then

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U30qHiEQWU8

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this Detox thing is so hopefully this isn't off topic

I came across this question by researching a missing YogaKit.modulemap not found kind of error (sorry I don't have the exact error) which I got after doing a `pod install`.

I fixed it by opening [project].xcworkspace then at the top `Product > Clean Build Folder`

OR

`shift + command + k`

Make sure Xcode has finished cleaning the build before trying to run the project again.

Answer (score 0):

On the Podfile target post install ...

```
post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if target.name == 'YogaKit'
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'
          end
        end
    end
  end
```